# PowerShell. How I can output first pair of "key" = value; from hash table, then do something, then continue to putput other pairs from collection?

Tags: powershell, iteration

```
$hash = [ordered]@{"Name" = "Con1"; "IP" = "192.168.0.44"; MAC = "00-00-00-11-22-33";}
```

I need output to be like that

```
Name "is" Con1
Details are:
IP "is" 192.168.0.44
MAC "is" 00-00-00-11-22-33
```

I know how to iterate thorugh keys in hashtable, but I can not understand how to:

1. Output first "key" = value; pair
2. Do something
3. Continue iteration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use a *functional* approach using [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7.2):

```sh
# Output first key/value pair (if there is any)
$hash.GetEnumerator() | Select-Object -First 1 | ForEach-Object {
    '{0} "is" {1}' -f $_.Key, $_.Value
}

'Details are:'

# Output all remaining key/value pairs (if there are any)
$hash.GetEnumerator() | Select-Object -Skip 1 | ForEach-Object {
    '{0} "is" {1}' -f $_.Key, $_.Value
}
```

---

Alternatively split the `hashtable` into *head* item and *tail* array.

```
# Collect the hashtable entries in an array @(), then split into head and tail
$head, $tail = @($hash.GetEnumerator())

# Output the head
'{0} "is" {1}' -f $head.Key, $head.Value

# Output the tail array
'Details are:'
$tail.ForEach{ '{0} "is" {1}' -f $_.Key, $_.Value }
```

Note this has some memory overhead as a new array is created, but it contains only references so this won't matter unless you have a really large amount of `hashtable` items.

---

Another alternative, *imperative* way is to use the [IEnumerator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerator?view=net-6.0) methods directly:

```sh
$hash = [ordered]@{"Name" = "Con1"; "IP" = "192.168.0.44"; MAC = "00-00-00-11-22-33";}
$enumerator = $hash.GetEnumerator()

# Output first key/value pair (if there is any)
if( $enumerator.MoveNext() ) { 
    '{0} "is" {1}' -f $enumerator.Current.Key, $enumerator.Current.Value
}

'Details are:'

# Output all remaining key/value pairs (if there are any)
foreach( $item in $enumerator ) { 
    '{0} "is" {1}' -f $item.Key, $item.Value
}
```

**Remarks:**

- `IEnumerator.MoveNext()` is somewhat counter-intuitive as it needs to be called *before* enumerating the 1st element. Otherwise the `IEnumerator.Current` property isn't populated.
- The `foreach` loop starts off, where `.MoveNext()` has left the enumerator, so it starts at the 2nd item.
- IMO the *functional* approach using `Select-Object` is clearer as each of the loops can be viewed in isolation and a quick glance at the `Select-Object` parameters tells us what is happening, whereas using the `IEnumerator` methods you have to consider what the current state of the enumerator is.

---

**Output for all variants:**

```sh
Name "is" Con1
Details are:  
IP "is" 192.168.0.44      
MAC "is" 00-00-00-11-22-33
```